# Actionscript 3, multiple audio tracks

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, mute

I have four different tracks(guitar, bass, drums, vocals) in a music-player. They are all named as checkboxes to check/uncheck which one of the tracks is hearable at the moment and i also have a play button to start off. So when check e.g vocals and guitar i only want to hear these two instruments and bass and drums just playing muted in the background.

Problem is when i start off with these two boxes checked i can not change the other boxes while playing because the status is static and doesn't dynamically change while hitting the boxes.

Just a excerpt of my code with only guitar and vocals for easy understanding:

```
        var vocals:Sound = new Sound();
        var vocalsChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
        var vocalsTransform = new SoundTransform();
        vocalsChannel.soundTransform = vocalsTransform;
        vocals.load(new URLRequest("songsample.mp3"));

        var guitar:Sound = new Sound();
        var guitarChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
        var guitarTransform = new SoundTransform();
        guitarChannel.soundTransform = guitarTransform;
        guitar.load(new URLRequest("funky.mp3"));

        voc_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _selectedVoc);
        git_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _selectedGit);

        function _selectedVoc(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var bool:Boolean = e.target.selected;

            if(bool)
            {
                vocalsTransform.volume = 1;

            }
            else
            {
                vocalsTransform.volume = 0;

            }
        }


        function _selectedGit(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var bool:Boolean = e.target.selected;

            if(bool)
            {
                guitarTransform.volume = 1;

            }
            else
            {
                guitarTransform.volume = 0;


            }
        }

        play_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
                                 function(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            vocalsChannel = vocals.play(0,0,vocalsTransform);
            guitarChannel = guitar.play(0,0,guitarTransform);
        })

        stop_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
                                 function(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            vocalsChannel.stop();
            guitarChannel.stop();
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the soundTransform property on the channel:

```
    function _selectedVoc(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var bool:Boolean = e.target.selected;

        if(bool)
        {
            vocalsTransform.volume = 1;

        }
        else
        {
            vocalsTransform.volume = 0;

        }
        vocalsChannel.soundTransform = vocalsTransform;
    }
```

Comment: @MarcelaThanks very much, this was the kind of advice i needed!

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answers your question, please make sure to select it as the answer.